# ExtraTreeRegressor in scikit-learn (Python)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

I have two questions on ExtraTreeRegressor in scikit-learn (Python).

1) Why is it not possible to increase the number of features above the dimension of the input space? The algorithm in [1] does not restrict the number of maximum features. In some cases selection a higher max_feature can result in better results.

2) We want to use the ExtraTreeRegressor for an implementation of fitted Q-iteration, where we execute the ExtraTreeRegressor inside a for loop (96 timesteps).
First, we set max_features to 1 and plotted the mse after ever iteration (upper graph).
Then we increased the max_features to the dimension of the input space ('auto') and plotted the mse. Why does the mse increases in the last case?

We would expect that the mse would be smaller with a larger value of max_features...

![The upper graph shows the mse inside the loop with max features set to 1, the lower graph shows the mse inside the loop with max_features set to 'auto'][1]

Figure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYEZw.jpg

[1] P. Geurts, D. Ernst., and L. Wehenkel, "Extremely randomized trees", Machine Learning, 63(1), 3-42, 2006.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the parameter `max_features` refers to the maximum number of features *per tree* which can be selected. What this means is that each tree in the forest can select up to `n_features` - which would likely result in overfitting since each tree is seeing everything (which is the opposite of what you want in bagged tree algorithms). A better diagnostic plot would probably be to look at training and testing error over the range of `max_features` - you should see a sweet spot where the model complexity captures the training and testing error well without overfitting.

To make `n_features` larger than the number of features in your data, you could build a pipeline and do a random projection to a higher dimensional space, then fit this model in the new space. By default, I don't believe the `ExtraTreesRegressor` has this functionality, since sklearn has Pipeline objects that can do this.